# Client finished message in TLS 1.2?

Tags: tls1.2

I am implementing tls 1.2 and i'm stuck on client finished message. My question is what is the size and structure of client finished message in tls 1.2 when using ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher.
I googled this question someone said its size is 48 byte

->12 byte verify data

->1 byte handshake type

->3 byte verify data length

-> and 32 byte MAC

is it rigth? And according to RFC 5246 finished message have **{verify_data[verify_data_length]}**

and **verify_data = PRF(master_secret, finished_label, hash(handshake_messages)**

and according to RFC 5246 section 5

**PRF(secret, label, seed) = P_(secret, label+seed)**

and **P_hash(secret, seed) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(1) + seed)**

and when i compute HMAC using sha256 for verify_data its size is 32 byte. So i'm confused in verify_data size and finished message structure. Kindly someone guide me to the right path.

Comment: Can I ask why you have C#, C and C++ tagged with this question all very different languages

Comment: i just need concept no matter which language is used.

Comment: There might be some useful information here with the references it makes.  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65622/client-server-encryption-technique-explanation-tls-ecdhe-rsa-with-aes-128-gcm-s

Answer (score 1):

The Client Finished message structure for ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 in TLS v1.2 is:
1 byte: handshake type, 0x14 for Finished message
3 bytes: length of verify data, 0x00000c for 12 bytes
12 bytes: verify data, computed as you indicated, e.g., 0x32c2b389cb39b3f5f7e657db

This is the Finished message, which in this case is the 16 bytes
1400000c32c2b389cb39b3f5f7e657db

The 32 bytes you mention for the SHA256 MAC are not part of the message.  MACs are incorporated at the record layer, when the message is encrypted.  As the Finished message is sent after the Change Cipher Spec message, it is always encrypted.

For AES CBC the MAC is appended to the encrypted data, so you would see the last 32 bytes as a MAC.  However, for GCM, things are different.  There is an 8 byte nonce, the encrypted data, and a 16 byte tag.  More info:
 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288 (AES GCM cipher suites)
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5289 (elliptic curve AES GCM cipher suites)